# Circle with border looks not circular, jagged and not smooth, why?

Tags: html, css

why is my css circle not smooth?

If i do a HTML5 Canvas its really nice.

```
<div id="circle"></div>
    <style>
    #circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border:4px solid blue;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkBp8/

Using Chrome and latest IE

Notice the extreme top bottom right left points appear flat.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you think you are using `50%` but you aren't, you have used `border-radius: 50px;` but that's wrong, you are using `border` of `4px` which you forgot to add to the box sizing of your element *(If you are aware of how box model of CSS really works)*.

So you should be using `border-radius: 54px;` instead cuz your total element's `height` and `width` sums up to `108px` counting border on both the sides.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/nkBp8/1/)

---

It is better if you use `50%` in such cases

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/nkBp8/2/)

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:4px solid blue;
}
```

---

If you want to stick with the `50px` measurement, than you can alter the box model rendering by using `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/nkBp8/4/) *(Altered Box Model)*

Answer (score 6):

You should use border-radius as a percentage, like this :

```
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
```

Answer (score 2):

For a circle shape using CSS, you should specify the same width as height (like you did), but you should always use `50%` on your border radius. This is because when specifying a width and height, it will not be including the padding and border widths. This means that on either side of your div there's 4px of border, which is slightly stretching out your div.

Also, you can remove the browser prefixes such as `-webkit-` and `-moz-`. Chrome 4 and Firefox 3.6 are [the last versions to need these prefixes](http://caniuse.com/border-radius) and [those really lack any browser usage share at all](http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php).

Your final code would look like this:

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:4px solid blue;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkBp8/3/)