# How to set smooth border-radius more than 50%

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with border radius.

i need set border radius such as this

[image]

Css border radius such as

```
    border-top-right-radius: 46%;
    border-top-left-radius: 21%;
```

give me bad result. Is it any way to make smooth radius?

Comment: Instead of `46%` try `50%` and `21%` to `25%`. Also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464405/circle-with-border-looks-not-circular-jagged-and-not-smooth-why) may can help you.

Comment: no, i need a smooth line. 50% gives me a circle, but i need more plastic border radius, to set smooth rounding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you may cut off your borders with 2 values for each corners, you can also use pixel units

```css
html {
  background:#023C5C;
}

div {
  text-align:center;
  background:#007EAA;
  min-height:200px;
  border-radius: 400px 70px 0 0 / 100px 10px 0 0;
  width:500px
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It is that i need