# CSS circle warps up not smooth / circular

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a collapsable sidebar and I want to have a circle with the username initials (pretty standard nowadays).

Currently I'm getting this jagged 'circle':

[image]

And this is the desired result:

[image]

I've been reading old questions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464405/circle-with-border-looks-not-circular-jagged-and-not-smooth-why)) and their answers but I didn't find any solution.

[LIVE JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/8/)

I guess something is wrong here:

```
.userInitials {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  color: #193D4C;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your circle element is being shrinked by the flex display. Use `flex-shrink:0`. Also you can set a `display:flex` and `justify-content:center;align-items:center;` to your element. Something like this:

```
.userInitials {
  height: 38px; /* increase height */
  flex-shrink:0; /* add property, value 0 so no srhink */
  display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center; /*center the initials */
  width: 38px; /* increase width */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  color: #193D4C;
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. As a curiosity, how did you know it was related to flex?

Comment: Experience :) It happens to you only once and it's so frustrating you remember it. You could read more on flex, but... it's a  damn rabbit hole! Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you. Cheers

Comment: @avia
Thanks for reminding about `flex-shrink`, because I'm used to lock the width with min-width and max-width and that kinda looks not good

Comment: @Getsumi3 yes, flex has *a lot* of many subtle things to consider, like I said, a rabbit hole for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set min and max width to 32px for `.userInitials`

Also I'd recommend to make some changes:

- modify the next `div` (the one after `span`):

```
align-items: flex-start !important; 
width: 100%;
justify-content: space-between;
```

- modify the `div` that holds the `staff-name` and `staff-position`:

```
width: 100%;
```

- modify the chevron:

```
remove margin-left or set it to a value between 3 and 10 px
```

Here is [modified demo](https://jsfiddle.net/swz8dgha/8/)

I've added `.staff-nav-holder` to make it easier to modify.
Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations, I wish I could accept 2 answers!

Comment: Sure, no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

did you try to make the border radius a px value, it usually works by using half the pixels you set the square to be.

in this case use `border-radius: 16px`